# In mvc2 or jquery how to set limited characters in textbox

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-2, maxlength

I have Address field in my web form.. I want to limit the characters in that textbox.. I don't know how to do this by mvc2..

**My html code**

```
<%: Html.TextBox("Address",Model.Address, new {@title="Enter your address"}) %>
```

If any chances in jquery is there means it will ok..

Comment: I dont know that asp stuff, but using the the attribute map and adding maxlength=30 could do it?
<%: Html.TextBox("Address",Model.Address, new {@title="Enter your address",@maxlength=30}) %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is `maxlength="x"` where `x`: length

```
<%: Html.TextBox("Address",Model.Address, new {@title="Enter your address", @maxlength="10"}) %>
```

Or using jQuery,

```
$('#Address').attr('maxlength', '10');
```